# How to reorder React components with CSS Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, responsive, css-grid

```
|----------|
| Form     |
|----------|   //current layout
| Bookings |
|----------|


|----------|
| Bookings |
|----------|   //desired layout
| Form     |
|----------|
```

How can I change the order of the compoents so that I can display `<Bookings />` component before the `<form>`?

The solution should not change the JSX file order of components, as this is only desirable in one of the many breakpoints.

JSX file

```
<main className="Form-container">
  <form className="booking-form-business">
     <WorkingHours />
  </form>
  <ContextProvider>
     <Bookings /> //main div has a 'bookings' class
  </ContextProvider>
</main>
```

SCSS file

```
.Form-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);

    .booking-form-business {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }

    .bookings { //how to display this before 'booking-form-business'
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use javascript to change the elements styles (document.querySelector('.bookings').style += "grid-row: 1/2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `order` property when you have `display: grid`

```
.Form-container {
    .booking-form-business {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      order: 2;
    }
    .bookings {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      order: 1;
    }
}
```